# How to get tag of an open default Warning-Dialog (warndlg) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Assume I have created a basic Warning-Dialog like:

```
warndlg('Some Message')
```

without assigning a handle. However I would like to get the handle by finding it like this:

```
handle_to_warndlg = findall(0,'Type','Figure','Tag','XXX');
```

But I do not know the the default 'Tag', 'XXX' assigned by MATLAB to the figure.

What string do I need to replace 'XXX' with?

Comment: On R2016b the default tag seems to be `'Msgbox_Warning Dialog'`. Check yourself with `h = warndlg('Some Message'); get(h)`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'll post as an answer then, so that you can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On R2016b the default tag seems to be `'Msgbox_Warning Dialog'`.

Check yourself with

```
h = warndlg('Some Message');
get(h, 'Tag')
```

Comment: The method is also feasible with R2016A.